# Custom phtml cannot access $block

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, phtml

Im trying to add a custom .phtml file via XML to the product_view. This is what I have done:

In the **catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ku.atrributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/ku-attributes.phtml" before="product.info.main"/>
    <move element="ku.atrributes" destination="page.main.title" />
```

In the **ku-attributes.phtml**:

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    echo $_product->getData('ku_untetitel');
?>
```

**Result**:
I only get the Product Title on a white, unformatted Page.

Whats wrong with this? What am I doing wrongly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` block type write `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! Can you maybe specify why I do not have access to $block in the other class?

Comment: @Atr_Max because in Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template in this class you don't have current product object , that's why you didn't get information

Comment: I like to test out what block classes i have with `var_dump(get_class($this))` when i'm playing around or just for a sanity check.